# write records from many files to one file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have three files. File1 has record like

```
abc|123
bcd|234
cde|345
```

and File2 has records like

```
12
13
```

and File3 has records like

```
Add|xyz.txt|04
Add|str.txt|05
Del|uyt.txt|99
```

Here i'm trying to put records of all files into one file.So output(final.txt) will look like

```
abc|123|12|Add|xyz.txt|04
bcd|234|13|Add|str.txt|05
cde|345|  |Del|uyt.txt|99
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `paste`:-

```
paste -d'|' file1 file2 file3
abc|123|12|Add|xyz.txt|04
bcd|234|13|Add|str.txt|05
cde|345||Del|uyt.txt|99
```

Answer (score 0):

With an extra effort to preserve spaces for better alignment, also consider to use `column`

```
paste -d'|' file1 file2 file3 | column -tns '|'

abc  123  12  Add  xyz.txt  04
bcd  234  13  Add  str.txt  05
cde  345      Del  uyt.txt  99
```

You can replace the delimiter back through `sed`

```
paste -d'|' file1 file2 file3 | column -tns '|' | sed 's/\([^ ]\)  /\1|/g;s/  \([^ ]\)/|\1/g'

abc|123|12|Add|xyz.txt|04
bcd|234|13|Add|str.txt|05
cde|345|  |Del|uyt.txt|99
```